# How to discretize a nonlinear system

Tags: matlab, control-theory, casadi

How can i discretize the following nonlinear system. Im using Matlab and Casadi for Model Predictive Control. The Constant C is betwenn 0 and 1.

```
dx/dt = C * x/(x^2 + 1)
```

Thank you for your time and Help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if you want to use the file to discretize a differential equation, there are a lot of methods such as simple Euler, Runge-Kutta, and so on. Let me say how to use the Euler method. based on the differential definition:

```
dx/dt = (x(i+1) - x(i))/dt
```

here i is the discretization index and dt is sample time (typically 0.01). If I have to use your equation:

```
(x(i+1) - x(i))/dt = C*x(i)/(x(i)^2 + 1)
```

after simplification:

```
x(i+1) = x(i) + dt*(C*x(i)/(x(i)^2 + 1))
```

this is your discretized model. In matlab, just use the following code:

```
C = 0.5;
N = 100;
x(1) = 1;       % initial condition
dt = 0.01;

i = 1;
for i = 1:N
    x(i+1) = x(i) + dt*(C*x(i)/(x(i)^2 + 1));
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are just looking to build it from blocks, something like this should work:

[image: simulink block diagram]

You basically need to invert the formula to:

```
x = int(C * x/(x^2 + 1))
```

Everything to the right of the equal sign then feeds the input to the integrator and the output of the integrator becomes `x`.